# Python HTMl Scrape Not Yielding A Result

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

(New to Python and 1st post)

See code below, but here's the issue:
I'm trying to scrape the webpage in the code for all job titles on the page, but when I print the list, I'm not getting any values. I've tried using different xpaths to see if I could get something to print, but every time my list is always empty.

Does anyone know if it is an issue with my code, or if there is something about the site structure that I didn't consider?

Thanks in advance!

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get("https://careers.homedepot.com/job-search-results/?location=Atlanta%2C%20GA%2C%20United%20States&latitude=33.7489954&longitude=-84.3879824&radius=15&parent_category=Corporate%2FOther")
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

Job_Title = tree.xpath('//*[@id="widget-jobsearch-results-list"]/div/div/div/div[@class="jobTitle"]/a/text()')

print (Job_Title)
```

Comment: Forgot to follow up to this, but I thought I'd point out that Selenium did the trick. See below for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Information that you're looking for is generated dynamically with some `JavaScript` while `requests` allows to get just initial `HTML` page source.

You might need to use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)(+[`chromedriver`](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.28/)) to get required data:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://careers.homedepot.com/job-search-results/?location=Atlanta%2C%20GA%2C%20United%20States&latitude=33.7489954&longitude=-84.3879824&radius=15&parent_category=Corporate%2FOther")
xpath = "//a[starts-with(@id, 'job-results')]"
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
jobs = [job.text for job in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]
```

Comment: Some of the other posts mentioned that there is some JS in there. Is there a good way to tell if its JS having no current knowledge of JS?

Thanks for the comment, I'll try out some of these ideas when I get a chance.

Comment: You can simply right click on page in browser and then click on `Page source` in context menu to see the page source before browser execute any `JavaScript`. If there is no required data, then you can be sure that data generated dynamically by `JavaScript`

Comment: Just ran this. It seems like a step in the right direction for what I'm working on. Thank you! Just need to get more familiar with Selenium now haha

Answer (score 1):

Try a library that can parse JS ([dryscrape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape) is a lightweight alternative).

Here's a code sample

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import dryscrape

session = dryscrape.Session()
session.visit("https://careers.homedepot.com/job-search-results/?location=Atlanta%2C%20GA%2C%20United%20States&latitude=33.7489954&longitude=-84.3879824&radius=15&parent_category=Corporate%2FOther")
page = session.body()
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

Job_Title = tree.xpath('//*[@id="widget-jobsearch-results-list"]/div/div/div/div[@class="jobTitle"]/a/text()')

print (Job_Title)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out when I get a chance.

How are you able to tell that its JS? (Haven't learned any yet) Everything looked like a mix if HTML, CSS, and some Python[I think] to me.

Comment: I ended up going with the Selenium solution that Andersson posted. I think dryscrape would have worked well based on what I read, but it doesn't seem to support Win (which is what I use).

Answer (score 0):

That page build HTML(table) with JS. In other words, Target block does not exist as HTML on that page. Please open the source and check it.

```
<div class="entry-content-wrapper clearfix">
    <div id="widget-jobsearch-results-list"></div> # <- Target block is empty!
    <div id="widget-jobsearch-results-pages"></div>
</div>
```